# Android fail to copy byte data to an empty file

Tags: java, android

Hello i'm building a small app which use an 12Mb database.
Because of the db size i have to copy it from the asset folder, i'm using a byte array to copy data to an empty file :

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db){

   try{

      //Getting the asset db
      InputStream myInput = this.context.getAssets().open("dicoMots.db");

      //Creating the empty db to receive bytes
      String outFileName = "/data/data/"+this.context.getApplicationContext().getPackageName()+"/databases/dicoMots.db";
      OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

      //Transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
      byte[] buffer = new byte[14336000];

      int length;
      while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0){
          myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
      }

      //Close the streams
      myOutput.flush();
      myOutput.close();
      myInput.close();      

      Log.d("DICO", "Database loaded");
   }
   catch(Exception e){
       Log.d("DICO", "Database load fail");
   }
}
```

The empty file is successfully created and the input file is readed as well. The value returned by myInput.read is also correct.
But the output file remains empty and no data is copied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this method is working for me

```
private void copyDataBase() throws IOException {

    InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);

    String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;

    OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int length;
    while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
        myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }

    myOutput.flush();
    myOutput.close();
    myInput.close();
}
```